# throw exceptions or not when check the parameters of a method?

Tags: c#, exception

I like to check that all the parameters of the method have the correct information before doing something with them. Something like this:

```
public method(MyType param1)
{
try
{
    if(param1 == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Error1");
    }
    if(param1.Property1 == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Error2");
    }

    if(param1.Property1.Amount <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Error3");
    }

    ...


    //Do what I need with the parameter
}
catch { throw; }
}
```

However, [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793405/c-sharp-either-return-false-or-do-nothing) someone comments that it is not a good idea to throw an exception as normal flow, but I am not sure if this is the case or not, because if I have to check the parameters and also there are exceptions like `ArgumentNullException` and `ArgumentException` that it seems that it can be thrown when there are some problem with parameters, it makes me to wondering if really it is a bad way to do, the example that I comment.

Another reason that another user gives it is that an exception consume 4000-8000 cycles of CPU. Well, the objective in my case it is to know if there are some error with the parameters and really if the application works as expected, the exception will never be thrown, so in practice, if the application has no bugs then the performance doesn't decrease.

So in summary, I would like to know how is the best way to handle the check of the parameters before continuing with the process.

Thanks.

Comment: Exceptions are expensive, but passing in bad data is more expensive. I don't see a problem with (and would encourage) throwing exceptions here. After all, you're not going to do this is a tight loop so the cost isn't an issue.

Comment: You can remove `try {} catch{ throw; }` though.

Comment: Yes you should throw exceptions for failed preconditions although you shouldn't wrap the whole method in a `try { } { catch throw; }`.

Comment: I wouldn't use `ArgumentNullException` for the second case - the value of `param1` isn't null by that point, so the *argument* isn't null, even though some property of the object it refers to is.

Comment: the key thing is "as normal flow". If something is expected then you shouldn't throw an exception. If something isn't then exceptions are fine. So in the case somebody is calling a method wrong exceptions are absolutely the way to go. So as an example if you have a string you are parsing that could be null then you shouldn't throw a null argument exception. If however the string should always be not null then throw that exception.

Comment: @Lee why it is not a good idea to wrap the whole method in a try/catch?

Just for curious, because if just throw throw the exception I don't see the problem, aslo it could happen another exceptions in the rest of the method. So I am wondering the reason why it is not a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: If you know you're going to be throwing exceptions, then why bother wrapping it at all? Feel free to try/catch the rest of the method of course, just not the parameter checks.

Comment: Because you're simply re-throwing any exceptions without handling them in any way so the block is redundant. If you can handle exceptions in some area of the code you should limit the scope of the `try/catch` block to that region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throwing exceptions after argument validation is a good approach. This way you explicitly let the developer using your method know that he is calling it incorrectly, which enables him to easily fix this bug.

I would definitely get rid of the `try...catch` part, though. It is absolutely redundant and makes the code more complex than it needs to be (and slightly confusing).

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely throw exceptions when a required value is null or missing. One of the things I like to do to clean up this type of situation is use a method to check if the Type is valid, and use Exception annotations when my code might throw an exception.

The down side is that, if used correctly the Validate(...) method gets called twice. I like the Validate(...) approach because it allows a change to find the error prior throwing the exception, because any class can call Validate(...)

```
class MyClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// DoSomething
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">InvalidOperationException</exception>
    public void DoSomething(MyType myType)
    {
        string errorMessage;
        if (!Validate(myType, out errorMessage))
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Argument myType is not valid: {0}", errorMessage));

        // Finish
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// IsValid
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">ArgumentNullException</exception>
    public static bool Validate(MyType myType, out string errorMessage)
    {
        errorMessage = null;

        if (myType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("myType");           
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myType.Property1))
            errorMessage = "Property1 is required";
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myType.Property2))
            errorMessage = "Property2 is required";

        return errorMessage == null;
    }
}

class MyType
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```